# Can't upload a file to Autodesk Forge OSS bucket

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

I have created an OSS bucket and I'm trying to upload a file to it, but getting an error every time.  Here is my bucket:

```
{
  "dictionary": {
    "bucketKey": "-removed my client id-------------test1",
    "bucketOwner": "-removed my client id------------",
    "createdDate": 1661180310185,
    "permissions": {
      "dictionary": {
        "0": {
          "dictionary": {
            "authId": "-removed my client id------------",
            "access": "full"
          },
          "count": 2
        }
      },
      "count": 1
    },
    "policyKey": "temporary"
  },
  "count": 5
}
```

When I try to upload a CAD file to the bucket, I get an error as shown below.  I have created a few buckets with another app, and even gone so far as to remove my old app and create a new one.  Same issue.

```
Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiException: Error calling UploadObject: {"reason":"No write access"}
   at Autodesk.Forge.ObjectsApi.UploadObjectAsyncWithHttpInfo(String bucketKey, String objectName, Nullable`1 contentLength, Stream body, String contentDisposition, String ifMatch, String contentType)
   at Autodesk.Forge.ObjectsApi.UploadObjectAsync(String bucketKey, String objectName, Nullable`1 contentLength, Stream body, String contentDisposition, String ifMatch, String contentType)
   at PE_AutodeskForgeService.Controllers.OSSController.UploadObject(UploadFile input) in D:\Code\PE_AutodeskForgeService\PE_AutodeskForgeService\Controllers\OSSController.cs:line 127
   at lambda_method61(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36 Edg/104.0.1293.63
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryr5CxWcAi4docJmf4
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/swagger/index.html
Content-Length: 364166
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="104", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="104"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
```

Pretty sure this isn't a Scope issue, as scope is set as shown below:

```
        public static async Task<dynamic> GetInternalAsync()
        {
            if (InternalToken == null || InternalToken.ExpiresAt < DateTime.UtcNow)
            {
                InternalToken = await Get2LeggedTokenAsync(new Scope[] { Scope.BucketCreate, Scope.BucketRead, Scope.BucketUpdate, Scope.BucketDelete, Scope.DataRead, Scope.DataWrite, Scope.DataCreate, Scope.CodeAll });
                InternalToken.ExpiresAt = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(InternalToken.expires_in);
            }

            return InternalToken;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check two things:

- that your code is generating the token for the same Forge Client ID that owns the bucket
- that your Forge subscription is valid (if it's a trial, perhaps it has expired?)

And if none of the above helps, please share your Forge Client ID and the name of one of the problematic buckets with us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`.

Comment: I found a github repo from JoaoMartins-Forge that has code to allow access to the ‘new’ way to upload files to Forge.  I have it implemented, but I’m still getting a error where I am unable to upload files to a provided bucket.  I also just built and used his code directly, no change except for my app ID and secret.

I feel like this is an issue upstream in the .NET 6 SDK implementation of the Autodesk.Forge library.  I can upload objects to buckets just fine if I roll back to an older version of the Autodesk.Forge .NET SDK, specifically 1.6.0 targeting .NET runtime 4.0.3+